# How to specify ssl connection with Nginx stream?

Tags: ssl, nginx, docker

Im trying to define reverse proxy with nginx.

I have a server which listens on port 943 (TCP with SSL). I use [tekn0ir/nginx-stream](https://hub.docker.com/r/tekn0ir/nginx-stream/) docker. I have the following definitions in `myotherservice.conf` file:

```
upstream backend {
hash $remote_addr consistent;

server myserverip:943;
}

server {
listen localhost:943;
proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
proxy_timeout 300s;
proxy_pass backend;
}
```

When Im trying to connect loslhost:943, it refused. Im suspect its related to my SSL definitions. How should I define it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with docker you must to bind port to all container interfaces in order to be able to expose ports:

```
...
server {
  listen *:943;
...
```

[Doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen)